# How to load encrypted csv file into spark Dataset<Row>?

Tags: csv, apache-spark, encryption

I need to extract the contents of an encrypted csv file (header included) into a dataset. what is the best way to read an encrypted file? The file will be encrypted using AES256 algorithm. I can modify the encryption algorithm(256) based on what spark can support.

Comment: AFAIK Spark does not have APIs to decrypt. If decrypting outside of spark before `spark.read.format("csv").load(...)` then consider reading them as RDD through `sc.binaryFiles` and the write an UDF to decrypt in memory.

Comment: We need to encrypt files in HDFS and cannot have decrypted file on disk.. I will try loading the file using binaryFiles->decrypt->load to dataset. wish there was a library to do this. Any reason why decryption is not part of spark?

Comment: AFAIK encryption at rest is handled by HDFS at service level (encrypts the blocks) and files themselves are not encrypted. S3 on the other hand has client-side encryption and so a method is available: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/aws/amazon-s3.html#client-side-s3-encryption.I would think this is not implemented as it is not a widespread ask but it would be best to check Hadoop conf.

Comment: Hi, @Sai, I indeed start doing this. Open binary RDD, on pure JVM code I decrypt the file, now I get a huge byte array. If CSV, I could myself wrap it in string, split by line, by delimiter, etc. - however what if the encrypted file is Avro or Parquet? I cannot use .format.load because the content is already on a RDD, how I tell spark that the RDD content is Parquet, CSV, JSON, Avro etc.?

Comment: @RicardoPiccoli Decrypting in memory and inferring would be elegant, but I don't think there are any libs that can do this rn.
You could write the data to a temp directory (executor local or HDFS/ S3) and then read it back as Parquet etc and then `union` them.

Comment: @Sai, indeed. I tried to create my own HDFS input format and record reader and it became very hard. My idea was to define the delimiter as a fix length where we could apply parallel AES decryption. One day I will do, at least for text encrypted content, such as CVS and JSON... Avro could even be possible... PS: what I ended up doing was: encrypt the source text file, line by line, keeping line delimeter, and then load the RDD as a text file, decrypt record by record as a map function and then indeed, you have one text record to explode CSV colums.